# syntax issue with sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, sp-executesql

I'm trying to write a stored procedure and I keep getting this error that I haven't defined @address , which I did. I know I'm missing a little thing , how should I change this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE search_domaintable
@link nvarchar(50),
@address nvarchar(50)
AS
EXEC ('SELECT rank , ip FROM dbo.['+@link+'] where [address]=@address ');
```

I tried this one too:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE search_domaintable
@link nvarchar(50),
@address nvarchar(50)
AS
EXEC ('SELECT rank , ip FROM dbo.['+@link+'] where [address]=['+@address+']');
```

but it takes @address value as a column name and tells me such column doesn't exist.

Comment: well....you aren't actually using `sp_executesql`

Comment: in the first one, there is nothing setting the value of the @address variable. In the second, try printing out the generated string and see if it executes...it won't because you don't have string delimiters...  Please read this article thoroughly. http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

the stored procedure should be like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE search_domaintable
@link nvarchar(50),
@address nvarchar(50)
AS
EXEC ('SELECT rank , ip FROM dbo.['+@link+'] where address  = ''' + @address + '''');
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, `@link` should be of type `sysname`.